# How to get a ruby class when it's name is in a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm passing a string with the name of an activerecord model class into my method and I want to be able to call some methods on that class.

This is wrong:

```
def perform(body_class, body_id)
  body = body_class.constantize
  request = body.find(body_id)
end
```

Update - that actually works fine.

Comment: Why exactly is it wrong? That's precisely what you'd do if you have ActiveSupport available, and since you tagged this with Rails, it's presumable that you do.

Comment: That should work. Are you sure that `body_class` is a valid class name?

Comment: Oh! Seems like I had the capitalisation wrong in the body_class I was passing. It's working now. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting? Make sure the string is in the correct ActiveRecord format.

For example:

```
"Person".constantize # works
"person".constantize # does not work
```

To get the second one to work you should also add `camelize`

```
"person".camelize.constantize # works
```